# Read binary file of integers of non-standard bit length in Python

Tags: python, matlab, binaryfiles

I have a matlab script that loads values by reading non-standard length bits.

For example:

```
[file, errmsg] = fopen(FileName,'r');

year = fread(file,1,'ubit12','ieee-le'); 
month = fread(file,1,'ubit4','ieee-le'); 
day = fread(file,1,'ubit5','ieee-le'); 
version = fread(file,1,'ubit11','ieee-le');
```

The values loaded are:

```
year =2016
month =7
day =21
version =0
```

While the binary version of the file is:

```
11100000 01110111 00010101 00000000
```

(as retrieved by doing `'{0:08b}'.format(ord(byte))` in python)

In other words,

```
year -> 4 lsb of byte 2 + byte 1 (011111100000)
month -> 4 msb of byte 2 (0111)
day -> 5 lsb of byte 3 (10101)
version -> 3 msb of byte 3 + byte 4 (00000000000)
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

[Bit array](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) I think this what you need.